# How to set file permissions recursively with Maven Assembly plugin when including a directory?

Tags: maven, file-permissions, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm including a whole directory with maven-assembly-plugin, the config looks like this:

```xml
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/mydir</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>bin</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/mydir/bin</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/bin</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>770</fileMode>
        <directoryMode>777</directoryMode>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

I expected that it will set 770 mode for all the files inside /bin directory in the artifact, but it actually sets the default 644 mode and only mode of directory itself is affected.
Is there any way to tell Maven to set mode for everything inside a specific directory without using big workarounds?

Comment: You have the correct idea about what the fileMode and directoryMode pieces of the assembly-plugin do, and the configuration snippet looks correct (provided you are only planning to set these values for the bin directory and its files). What version of the maven assembly plugin are you using? Is there perhaps an OS-specific issue here (I tested on Mac + Debian)?

Comment: I'm using maven assembly plugin version 3.3.0, and I'm having this issue on Mac